# How to use the latest version of WebKit when making a browser in Eclipse on Windows? And is it possible to by-pass the Safari requirement?

Tags: windows, eclipse, webkit

I made a browser before in Visual Studio. But events occurred and Visual Studio 2010 dosen't work the same with Win8. So I'm trying to make a browser now for the next version based on Webkit, and I'm wondering, if I follow the instructions here (http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#howusewebkit) wouldn't I have an older version of WebKit? Because Safari is discontinued on Windows and Chrome now uses Blink. Also nowadays people don't have Safari on Windows, so is it possible to by-pass? Because on that website it states that the user need Safari in order to work.

So it boils down to how do I get the latest version of WebKit if I'm developing on Windows? And is it possible to by-pass the Safari requirement. Sorry, I'm sort of new to Eclipse if I sound noobish.